# Realm: What is the better way to create (or post) Realm Objects?

Tags: android, realm

I'm doing a sample of a form on Android where the user can create a person with her dog (one to one relationship), so I designed a person and dog model where each person object has a dog object (inside of person object). So when I click on the button to create a person object with his dog Android throws me this error:

> RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists:

The method that I used to create Realm Objects is copyToRealm

```
realm.copyToRealm(persona.getPerro());
realm.copyToRealm(persona);
```

But After a research for a solution I looked that people use copyToRealmOrUpdate

```
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(persona.getPerro());
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(persona);
```

And when I used it, My app worked. But I still have some doubts. I prefer to know what things I should consider to use `copyToRealmOrUpdate` instead of `copyToRealm` because now I'm working in an app development and I want to use Realm with the DB that I will use (Because of that I'm doing the person and dog sample to test how to work with Realm because then I will have to develop an app with a lot of fields and relationships between objetcs).

Why this error happens (`RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists:`
)?

What is the better way to create RealmObjects?

PD : each time i use

```
 copyToRealm or copyToRealmOrUpdate
```

method, I enclose it with `beginTransaction()` and `commitTransaction()`

Comment: what is your POJO class ?

Comment: The methods does pretty much what they say. `copyToRealm` will create a new copy each time, while `copyToRealmOrUpdate` will update any existing object if one exists. Note that this behaviour is recursive, so if you have an Object that references that do not have primary keys they will always get inserted again, never updated.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have primary key as integer

**0** is the default value for int fields, so if you have a **RealmObject** with **0** as the value for your code field, it means that `realm.createObject(YourRealmClass.class)` will fail with the error you mentioned

as it will create an object with the default value.

> What is the better way to create RealmObjects?

`copyToRealmOrUpdate()` is better to use as it first checks if record exists or not . If record exists then it will update if record does not exits it will insert new record .